# I have a job offer but have to relocate. I have absolutely no money and nothing left. How can I get to the new city?

Tags: relocation

I have a job offer but have to relocate. I have absolutely no money and nothing left.  I do have a car but job is 700 miles. I asked for relocation loan from employer but was told they don't do that.

What can I do to get from my current city to the new one without the money?

Comment: Can you add details, like... when you interviewed did you discuss possible relocations and did you say you were open to it, etc. Or is the relocation a total surprise

Comment: Do you currently have a job? Can you borrow money from a bank?

Comment: Can you sell your car for bus fare? Can you hitch hike?

Comment: Deborah which country do you live in and how did you end up with no money ?

Comment: Hi Deborah, I put this on hold to give you time to add more details to this post, based on the questions in the comments. To give you a solid answer, we need to know more about your situation. I also edited this to make it more clear what your question is since we're a Q&A site and rank answers based on voting. Hope this helps.

Comment: Deborah, also, take a look at these questions: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31763/negotiating-relocation-compensation-after-starting-work and  http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31054/should-i-ask-for-relocation-or-a-sign-on-bonus-to-cover-moving-expenses. At the most, they may answer your question, at the very least, they're examples of how you might [edit] your post to flesh out more details. Once you edit, this post gets bumped to the top for review. Good luck!

Comment: Why would you apply for a job that far away if you couldn't get there?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Is it not obvious? She has no money.  It is a serious problem.  She has half solved it.

Answer (score 3):

You could explain your situation to the Salvation Army and check what services they can offer to people in your situation.

You could also try explaining your situation to the government public assistance, where they could give you a small emergency grant to keep you alive until your situation straightens out.